# What happens when FlurryWP8SDK.Api.EndTimedEvent isn't called?

Tags: logging, windows-phone-8, analytics, flurry, timed-events

What happens if FlurryWP8SDK.Api.LogEvent is called with a timed=true parameter but the FlurryWP8SDK.Api.EndTimedEvent is never called? Does the event still get logged without a time component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not end the timed event call, the timed event ends when the session is ended, i.e when the user quits the app.